# jsTree and AJAX > Load all data via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jstree

I am trying to use http://www.jstree.com as I am very happy with the demos, including the node types and the context menus. My problem is that I am not quite sure how to load the node data from within jstree using "json_data": { "ajax": { ... } }. All the documentation that I have read seems like you still need to define the parent data manually and the ajax calls are only for lazy-loading children nodes.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#file_tree').jstree({
    "plugins": ["json_data", "themes", "ui", "crrm", "dnd", "search", "contextmenu"],
    "themes": {"theme": "apple"},
    "ui": {"select_limit": 1, "selected_parent_close": "deselect", "disable_selecting_children": "true", "initially_select": [0]},
    "crrm": {"input_width_limit": "50", "move": {"always_copy": "multitree"}},
    "dnd": {"open_timeout": "700"},
    "search": {},
    "contextmenu": {"select_node": "true"},
    "json_data" : 
    {
        "ajax" : 
        {
            "url" : "{{ url('components/tree/findall') }}",
            // the `data` function is executed in the instance's scope
            // the parameter is the node being loaded
            // (may be -1, 0, or undefined when loading the root nodes)
            "data" : function (node) { 
                    console.info("Nodes:",node);    
                     return {   
                            "operation" : "get_children",
                            "id" : node.attr ? node.attr("id").replace("node_","") : 1
                        };
                    }
        }
    }
})
```

the url 'components/tree/findall' returns all nodes with parent_id = NULL and all their children within them (effectively returning ALL node data) in the form of JSON as follows:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Static Album 1","type":"folder","children":[{"id":3,"name":"Static Album 1.1","type":"folder","children":[]},{"id":4,"name":"Static Album 1.2","type":"folder","children":[]}]},{"id":2,"name":"Static Album 2","type":"folder","children":[{"id":5,"name":"Static Album 2.1","type":"folder","children":[]},{"id":6,"name":"Static Album 2.2","type":"folder","children":[]}]}]
```

But the route is never called upon loading the page (yes, I do have a div with id="file_tree"). If somebody has worked with jsTree and can give me some advise on how to get this working I would really appreciate it. Also, feel free to suggest alternatives if you feel that jsTree is not the goto solution for tree structures.

**EDIT:** I have gotten the route to call and retrieve data (turns out the jstree installed by bower is not working, so I downloaded a copy and placed it in my lib manually), but I am still not able to display any data. The elenent "node" in

```
"data": function(node) {....
```

Is just returning -1 (even though my firebug console shows all the data retrieved as above) and I'm not actually getting the data. I'm not really sure how this should be working...

Comment: So the URL key needs to return all of the root nodes, and the data key needs to return all of the children of the passed root node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just being an idiot. After getting the tree to actually load by downloading and manually copying jstree into my lib folder (instead of using the broken bower version), I just had to restructure my data on the server side before passing it to the jstree and viola!