# How to get jstree to work properly with ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

For a project I am trying to create an ajax-powered treeview control. My ajax scripts are working fine on the back end, but the tree is not being displayed properly. When I hard code the ajax response into my tree container, it is displayed properly:

[image: correct]

However, when I try to load the tree via ajax I get this:

[image: incorrent]

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function customMenu(node) {
        var items = {
            createItem : {
                label : "Generate random number(s)",
                action: function() {
                    console.log("Creating children...");
                    var selectedId = $("#treeview").jstree("get_selected").attr("id");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "libs/add.php",
                        data: "fact_id=" + selectedId,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return items;
    }

    $("#treeview").jstree({
        "plugins" : ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"], contextmenu: {items: customMenu, select_node: true}
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/display.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function(data) {
        $("#treeview ul").append(data);
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what my problem is? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
After looking closer, I realize that the exact problem is that the necessary classes are not being added to the child nodes when calling via ajax. Still, I'm not sure why.

**ANOTHER EDIT**
`display.php` now contains this response text:

```
[
    {
        "attr": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "data": 649,
            "state": "closed"
    },
    {
        "attr": {
            "id": 1
        },
       "data": 108,
       "state": "closed"
    },
    {
        "attr": {
            "id": 1
         },
        "data": 86,
        "state": "closed"
    },
    {
        "attr": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "data": 46,
        "state": "closed"
     }
]
```

Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Is your stylesheet being included, and have you set up correct URLs to the icons? It looks to me like that's why your data isn't being styled. **However**, looking at your code, a more likely reason that you aren't getting your styling is because you are just calling an arbitrary AJAX call outside the jsTree scope.

[Take a look at the docs for the `json_data` plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data) for jsTree. It's easy to use, provided you set up `display.php` correctly to only fetch the node that **jsTree is requesting**. It will make concurrent calls and get the nodes it needs, your script simply needs to serve them to it:

```
$("#treeview").jstree({
    "plugins" : ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
    "contextmenu": {
        items: customMenu,
        select_node: true
    },
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "libs/display.php",
            "data": function(n) {
                return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 
            }                        
        }
    }
});
```

The `json_data` plugin basically acts as a wrapper for a jQuery AJAX call, but the events are bound directly the jsTree core and the returned results are handled by jsTree. You'll probably need to tweak your return values a bit depending on what `display.php` is responding with, and what you have set your tree up to look like structurally.

> Edit

This is a similar post that might help you:
[jsTree and AJAX > Load all data via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276809/jstree-and-ajax-load-all-data-via-ajax?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for answering. So in what format should the response from `display.php` be? Currently, it just a JSON-encoded version of the entire ordered list.

Comment: Right at the top of that documentation page I linked to there are two examples of data structure you should return. Those examples relate directly to the example above that I copied from the docs, so if yours is different, you'll need to adjust both the code above and your `display.php` output accordingly

Comment: For example, in my application, I return this: `[{"data":{"title":"Node Title"},"attr":{"id":1,"rel":"node-type"},"state":"closed"}]`

Comment: Thanks again for your help so far. I think I have fixed my `display.php` script, but I'm still not quite sure how to display it. Please see my latest edit of the original post.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the children at all. It works kind of in the reverse, jsTree will call `display.php` and specify a **node ID** of which it wants all first level children of. If you specify `state: open` instead of `closed`, it should then go and look for the children of those nodes too. So `display.php` should accept a parameter like `$_GET['id']` and would look up all children of that ID, then return a formatted result like yours without all the children listed. Use `state: open` if you want to automatically load these nodes' children also.

Comment: What I'm not understanding is how to pass the IDs to the display script. I apologize, but the jstree documentation is severely lacking.

Comment: Based on what I am attempting, can you please give me an example that would allow me to use this `return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0`. I have no idea how to utilize this statement.

Comment: Sure - I agree that the jsTree docs are a little sub par. I suggest you `print_r($_GET)` in `display.php`. Because the `json_data` plugin is a wrapper for jQuery's AJAX call, you can use most of the same callbacks. Add `success: function(msg) { console.log(msg); return msg; }` after your `data` clause. This should log the return from `display.php` and still function as expected. Look in your console results and you should see an ID key of some sort that you can use as a parent ID key in `display.php`

Comment: I am trying my best to follow your instructions, but I am not sure where to start. The project instructions are as follows: create a treeview control where, when right-clicking a parent node, the option to generate 1-15 random numbers (within the specified range) as child nodes is given. What exactly should the code in `display.php` do? Should I be returning an ID from the database that corresponds to the ID of the parent node? Should I be echoing out a JSON object containing all the child nodes?

Comment: I have updated my original post to show the new response from `display.php` when the ID passed is `1`.

Comment: Change data: num to data: title: num. yes, you should be echoing a JSON object containing all the child nodes of the ID passed in. That return line in the Ajax is either returning the node ID of the one it's on, or ID **zero** for the default (first) node. You'll need to change that to whatever the ID is of your overall parent root node, and if you don't have one, you will need to return a list of the first parents when that root node ID (in this case zero) is passed in.